# What file formats are needed to be able to use our company logo in print and online?

Tags: svg, eps

I'm getting a logo made for use online and for print.  What file formats should I ask for.  The designer is giving me, eps, ai and pdf.  Should I also ask for svg?  thank you.

Comment: If you have access to the Illustrator, the ai file will give you the SVG file.  If you don't have access to Illustrator, you may want to ask for standard image formats (e.g. PNG, GIF, JPG, maybe with transparent backgrounds) in various resolutions.

Comment: You need to get the original files then it doesn't matter. Ask for the .AI or .PS files (or the In Design file).

Answer (score 2):

The main thing is to get the source file (and fonts). Most professionals use a vector based illustration program (like Adobe Illustrator) because the designs will scale without any jagged edges (aliasing) despite the ultimate output size. If your logo includes a font (that you wish to edit), you must have the font included with the file. If you don't need edits, you can have the font "flattened" so that it is simply just a bunch of lines and points like any other shape.

With the original file, (.ai for example, for Adobe Illustrator), you can easily export the logo into any format you want (including svg, eps, pdf, etc). If the designer used photoshop to design the file, make sure you get the .psd file.

Of course, if you don't have photoshop or illustrator, you'll definitely want to ask your designer to export these formats for you. It is very trivial to export the file into different graphic formats, so don't be shy about asking for a few of them to be done.

For web graphics, .png files are now pretty standard (but gif or jpeg will work). Most modern print layout programs will accept most graphic formats (including the original files themselves, if using Adobe InDesign), but .eps is pretty standard.

Comment: As of earlier than 2016, there are other programs, some of them free, which can open .ai files and export .svg files.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this fits under the scope of the site, but:

1. Ask for the native format that the designer uses.
    (You can always convert this later to a *lesser* format).
2. SVG is **scalable**. That is a good one.
3. PDF uses a bitmap format (Read: it gets fuzzy if you enlarge). **DO NOT WANT**.
   (Same for other bitmap formats. E.g. no JPG, no TIFF, no GIF ...)

Side note: Make sure you are in full agreement on who owns the logo. It might seem simple but in some countries the designer gets an awful lot of rights and you might just end up paying to use the logo on letter paper, but not on something else.

Comment: Your statement about PDFs is wrong. PDFs are basically just an extension of PostScript, which describes graphics as a programming language. EPS files are quite common for scalable graphics, and they do not use bitmaps. Of course you *can* have bitmaps in a PDF, but it's not exclusive. (A quick reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdf#Vector_graphics)

Comment: Ah. Last time I checked (7-ish years ago) all common PDF's used bmp format or jpeg format. Which make then non-scalable.  That was a while ago though.

Comment: Well, they *can*, and it certainly makes sense for photographic content, but in professional publishing, graphics are often embedded as EPS (thus vectorized), and this has always been the case, so it's not just a recent development or a new feature of the PDF standard (more like a fault of whoever published the PDFs you were looking at).